# The second user does not create

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When creating a new user with a completely different login, my error is displayed "This login is already busy. Try another.".

The following is displayed on the console:

> (sequelize) Warning: Model attributes (login) passed into finder
>   method options of model users, but the options.where object is empty.
>   Did you forget to use options.where? Executing (default): SELECT "id",
>   "login", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "users"
>   LIMIT 1; POST /api/auth/register 409 28.183 ms - 84

In what sense is "options.where"?

models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('users', {
        login: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        }
    })
    return User
}
```

controllers:

```
module.exports.register = async function(req, res) {
    const candidate = await User.findOne({
        login: req.body.login
    })

    if (candidate) {
        res.status(409).json({
            message: 'This login is already busy. Try another.'
        })
    } else {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        const password = req.body.password
        const user = new User({
            login: req.body.login,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        })
        try {
            await user.save()
            res.status(201).json(user)
        } catch(e) {
            errorHandler(res, e)
        }
    }
}
```

passport.js:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt
const User = require('../models/user')

const options = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), 
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
}

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
      new JwtStrategy(options, async (payload, done) => {
          try {
              const user = await User.findById(payload.userId).select('login id')

              if (user) {
                  done(null, user)
              } else {
                  done(null, false)
              }
          } catch(e) {
              console.log(e)
          }
      })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `options` object is the object expected by query functions on models, such as `findOne` (i.e. the parameter that you are passing to that function - [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOne)). The `options.where` attribute is an object that gets translated into the `WHERE` part of the generated SQL query.

Looking at your code I suppose that you want to find a user with login equal to `req.body.login`, in that case your code should look like this:

```
const candidate = await User.findOne({
    where: { 
        login: req.body.login
    }
})
```